# Crosswalk webview zoom

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

I've recently changed the webview for my custom Android device to Crosswalk from Android 4.2.2 implementation of the webview.

In the original implementation I could zoom in and out using

```
WebView.zoomIn();
```

and

```
WebView.zoomOut();
```

I can't however find anything like them with the Crosswalk webview.

Anyone did anything similar? Or is my best chance to implement and inject some javascript to scale the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the zooming by injecting javascript.

```
document.body.style.transform="scale(ZoomLevel)";
```